# How to get the "Server Name (Host Name)" in the "HTTP Request - Name" while recording the flow in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I would like to have "Server Name(Host Name)" along with "Path" in the "Http request - Name" filed.

I checked in the JMeter official documentation, Seems like we have only #{Name}, #{path} and #{counter} in the Naming format.

I don't need #{name} and #{Counter} so I just used #{Path} in the naming format, It is working fine but I want to add "Server Name(Host Name)" also along with the "Path" in the HTTP Request Name.

Attached few snapshots for reference.

Please let me know if there is any work around to do the same, Thanks in advance.

[Http Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjh5z.png) [Jmeter_Format_String_Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4req.png) [Test_Script_Recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh0mr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, at least not for [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5), the template format strings [include only those you've mentioned](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/proxy/DefaultSamplerCreator.java#L371).

```
if (httpSampleNameMode == SAMPLER_NAME_NAMING_MODE_FORMATTER) {
    return format.replaceAll("#\\{name([,}])", "{0$1")
            .replaceAll("#\\{path([,}])", "{1$1")
            .replaceAll("#\\{counter([,}])", "{2$1");
}
```

You can work it around by using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getCurrentSampler().getDomain(),)
```

it will save samplers with the above function name but when you run them in the [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) and in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) the function will be substituted by the respestive value of the target server IP or DNS hostname.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I will check and implement

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the server name during the recording phase. However, you can use a postprocessor to append required fields once the requests are created.

Jmeter template used to create sampler name is given below.

[image]